# jQuery Cycle2 slideshow squashed to the left in Safari on iphone

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

Hello and thanks for helping,
I have created a site here:

http://www.furniturebymartin.co.uk/index.html

The slideshow on the index page works beautifully on every browser except Safari, but only on Safari on the iPhone. Looks great on iPad. On the iPhone, it squashes the images to the left of the page. I have NO idea how to fix this. I've searched the internet for answers but no luck. If anyone could help, I'd be most grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved it myself! Again!

So, I set the  tag in the html code on the index.html page to

```
align="centre"
```

This set the slideshow to the middle of the page, although it was still squashed.

There was a section on the style sheet (styleMAIN.css) that was added at the suggestion of Cycle2 which looked like this:

```
/* media queries some style overrides to make things more pleasant on mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .cycle-slideshow { width: 480px;}
   .cycle-slideshow img { width: 100%; height: auto }
   .cycle-overlay { padding: 4px }
   .cycle-caption { bottom: 4px; right: 4px }
}
```

The setting of 480px for the width was too small on the iPhone in Safari, so I increased it to 720px. That is still narrower than the original, which is set at 800px for all other browsers, but large enough to work properly on an iPhone. The new css code looks like this:

```
/* media queries some style overrides to make things more pleasant on mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .cycle-slideshow { width: 720px;}
   .cycle-slideshow img { width: 100%; height: auto }
   .cycle-overlay { padding: 4px }
   .cycle-caption { bottom: 4px; right: 4px }
}
```

I cannot explain why the suggestion was to keep the width under 480px as it is obviously too small, but increasing it has worked.